# Initializing base class static const variable with derived class variable, via CRTP

Tags: c++, templates

The following program compiles and runs in Cygwin GCC 4.8.2 but not in MSCV 2008 (or MSVC 2013 either)

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    static const unsigned BAR = T::FOO;

    static void func()
    {
        std::cout << BAR << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<Derived<T> >
{
    static const unsigned FOO = 42;
};

int main()
{   
    Derived<int>::func();
}
```

MSVC error

```
Test.cpp(6) : error C2039: 'FOO' : is not a member of 'Derived<T>'
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
        Test.cpp(16) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Base<T>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=Derived<int>
        ]
        Test.cpp(24) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Derived<T>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
Test.cpp(6) : error C2065: 'FOO' : undeclared identifier
Test.cpp(6) : error C2057: expected constant expression
```

Is this program compliant or is this an MSCV issue? Also, is there a workaround?

Comment: I believe MSVC is correct (though I can't believe I just said that). `Base<Derived<T>>` has to be instantiated fully before `Derived<T>`, since it's a base, so `Derived<T>::FOO` shouldn't exist until after `Base<Derived<T>>` does, hence you can't reference it.

Comment: clang fails as well, which I believe is the correct behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 2 : it is enough to reject initialization after Derived class declaration.

The only way I could have MSVC and Clang compile your program is :

- reject Base::BAR initialization after Derived class declaration
- <del>use a concrete implementation of Derived to initialize BAR</del>

Edit : I think it is normal because in your code the compiler has no mean *when compiling Base* to know that T::FOO will exist and will be a constant value.

Current source is :

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    static const unsigned BAR;

    static void func()
    {
        std::cout << BAR << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<Derived<T> >
{
    static const unsigned FOO = 42;
};

template<typename T>
const unsigned Base<T>::BAR = T::FOO;

int main()
{   
    Derived<int>::func();
}
```

Comment: This too works:

    template<typename T>
    const unsigned Base<T>::BAR = Derived<T>::FOO;

Comment: @Olumide : I can confirm it works, but it means that for Derived<int>::func(), you use Derived<Derived<int> >::BAR, what is not what you originaly asked for ;-)

Comment: I meant to write `template<typename T> const unsigned Base<T>::BAR = T::FOO;`

Answer (score 0):

You can break the loop of dependencies between Base and Derive by not deriving Derive from Base (in the example you wrote this is not needed)

By the way, also clang fails to compile your example and gives the same errors as vstudio

```
#include <iostream>


template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    static const unsigned BAR = T::FOO;

    static void func()
    {
        std::cout << BAR << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived
{
    static const unsigned FOO = 42;
};

int main()
{
    Base<Derived>::func();
}
```